# Why is my cursor empty?

Tags: python, arcgis-10.0, arcpy, cursor

Yesterday I set up a [Python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29) script using a cursor on a layer.

Today I've tried running again and no matter what I run it in, the cursor is empty. I've tried removing the query on the layer, tried deleting the cursors and restarted my computer, but iterating through the rows in my table still does nothing. I've tried it directly on the FC (in SDE) and on the layer.

```
testcursor = arcpy.SearchCursor("testlayer")
```

Surely this should contain as many fows as the attribute table? Or have I got it wrong?

```
for row in testcursor:
    print "row exists"
    print row.getValue("SURVEY_NAME")
    survey = row.getValue("SURVEY_NAME")
    print survey
    if survey not in layerlist:
         layerlist.append(row.getValue("SURVEY_NAME"))
```

Yesterday this did something, but now it does nothing.

`layerlist` is empty

What have I done wrong?

Comment: try `for row in testcursor:`. Yesterday, you may have already had a global variable `rows` that was a cursor and unknowingly been referencing that. Also, consider changing this to use arcpy.da and to use a `with` statement. At least in what you have written, you also have no assignment of `layerlist`. Is `layerlist` initially assigned an empty list? Is `survey` still printing in the loop?

Comment: Just realized you are using 10.0, so no arcpy.da

Comment: More ideas: Do you have a selection currently applied to `testlayer`? Do you have a definition query on `testlayer`?

Comment: layerlist is an empty list I created before the cursor. Nothing prints in the loop.

Comment: @blord-castillo AHA. the selection - there wasnt one. (I still think this makes sense) but I tried recreated the testcursor with everything selected and everything works.
It doesn't really make sense to me but at least it works. thanks!

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't make sense, it should give you everything with no selection too. Maybe there was a selection applied that was empty (I think that is technically possible). I added the selection part as an answer below too so people don't have to dig through comments to find that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have a selection currently applied to `testlayer`? Do you have a definition query on `testlayer`?
Both of these can limit the number of records in the cursor when executed directly in ArcMap.

Answer (score 1):

Is 'rows' defined? Looks like you should be calling

```
for row in testcursor:
```

Try this:

```
# create empty list
LayerList = []

# create search cursor
testCursor = arcpy.SearchCursor(r'D:\workspace\testlayer')

for row in testCursor:
    if row.getValue("SURVEY_NAME"):
        survey = str(row.getValue("SURVEY_NAME"))
        print survey
        if survey not in LayerList:
            LayerList.append(survey)
```

Comment: Ah sorry I copied the wrong stuff into the question. that came from my desperation when I tried using different names for cursers. I've edited the question

Comment: could be an issue with field name vs. alias name. You might want to try arcpy.ListFields("testLayer") and make sure your indexing the field names the same as they are stored. Are you getting any errors, or is nothing printing?